# Como tranformar em Caixa Alta a primeira letra de palavras dentro de uma string

Tags: javascript

Tendo uma dada string, como colocar em letra grande (Caixa Alta) a primeira letra de cada palavra?

Por exemplo:

**original:** `'a música é universal'`
**Caixa Alta:** `'A Música É Universal'`

mas também nomes como `"anna-karin"` bem comum nos países nórdicos. Nesse caso devia ficar `"Anna-Karin"`.

Existe uma solução para todas as linguas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solução que encontrei, que funciona para a maior parte dos acentos em linguas *latinas* e *germânicas*, foi com regex:

```
string.replace(/([^A-zÀ-ú]?)([A-zÀ-ú]+)/g, function(match, separator, word){
    return separator + word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
});
```

Na regex procuro encontrar **um** caractér não presente nesta lista `[A-zÀ-ú]` (opcional, daí o `?`) e uma palavra de uma ou mais letras com `[A-zÀ-ú]+`, ambas com grupo de captura para poder trabalhar dentro da função do replace.

**Exemplo:**

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    return String(this).replace(/([^A-zÀ-ú]?)([A-zÀ-ú]+)/g, function(match, separator, word){
        return separator + word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    });
}

alert('a anna-karin gosta de música!'.capitalize());
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra possibilidade, criada pelo pessoal do PHP.JS com base na função [ucwords()](http://www.php.net/ucwords) do PHP:

```
function ucwords(str) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/
  // original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  // improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
  // improved by: Robin
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  //    input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
  //   example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
  //   returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
  //   example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
  //   returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'

  return (str + '')
    .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
      return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function ucwords(str) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/
  // original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  // improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
  // improved by: Robin
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  //    input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
  //   example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
  //   returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
  //   example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
  //   returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'

  return (str + '')
    .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
      return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}

alert( ucwords( 'num ninho de mafagafos tinha sete mafagafinhos' ) );
```

Comment: Boa sugestão, mas falha em nomes como "Anna-Karin" ou "O'Leary". Por exemplo a frase `"a anna-karin e o o'leary estão contentes"` dá `"A Anna-karin E O O'leary Estão Contentes"`.

Comment: Por se tratar de uma versão JS de uma função de outra linguagem eles tiveram de respeitar o formato de saída da função original. E, talvez porque tecnicamente "Anna-karin" e "O'leary" são uma única palavra, é isso que ucwords() do PHP retorna.