# Nomes em inputs, com primeiras letras maiúscula ignorando(de,do,da,das,dos etc)!

Tags: javascript, html

no qual nomes pessoais queria deixa ele mas organizado, tenho um script no qual deixa as primeiras letras maiúscula da nome, mas ele nao ignora os de, dos, das, da etc, queria saber se é possível add esse exceção ao script!

```js
function c(id) {
    var letra = document.getElementById(id).value;
    letra = letra.split("");
    var tmp = "";
    for (i = 0; i < letra.length; i++) {
        if (letra[i - 1]) {
            if (letra[i - 1] == " " || letra[i - 1] == ".") {
                letra[i] = letra[i].replace(letra[i], letra[i].toUpperCase());
            }
        } else {
            letra[i] = letra[i].replace(letra[i], letra[i].toUpperCase());
        }
        tmp += letra[i];
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = tmp;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="c('input-1')"  required class="inp_editar" type="text" name="nome_cont" id="input-1"/>
```

Obg!

Comment: Dei [uma resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42172/129) sobre isso. Para impedir de fazer letra grande palavras curtas é preciso uma lista delas. Tens uma lista?

Comment: basicamente é só das, dos, e, do, da

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desenvolvendo mais [a outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42173/129) podes fazer assim:

```
var ignorar = ["das", "dos", "e", "é", "do", "da", "de"];
function caixaAlta(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/([^A-zÀ-ú]?)([A-zÀ-ú]+)/g, function(match, separator, word) {
        if (ignorar.indexOf(word) != -1) return separator + word;
        return separator + word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    });
}

var testes = ['a música é universal', 'a democracia é de todos'].map(caixaAlta);
console.log(JSON.stringify(testes)); // ["A Música é Universal","A Democracia é de Todos"]
```

E quando encontrares uma palavra que não está na lista, adiciona.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LgLz5znq/

---

### E para integrares isso no teu código podes fazer assim:

HTML:

```
<input onkeyup="corrigirValor(this)" ...etc
```

repara que usando o `this` já estou a passar o próprio elemento, não preciso de passar IDs.

JavaScript:

```
function corrigirValor(el) {
    el.value = caixaAlta(el.value);
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/LgLz5znq/1/

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou perfeitamente!