# Filtrar nomes de arquivos em uppercase e com determinado trecho no fim

Tags: regex

Tenho alguns arquivos nomeados com nomes de pessoa, porém alguns estão completamente em maiúsculo, outros completamente em minúsculo e alguns até com case misturados.

Gostaria de montar uma regex para, a partir de uma lista, filtrar somente os nomes de arquivos que fossem totalmente em uppercase, sem conter o trecho `- Cópia` antes da extensão.

O trecho no fim eu consigo detectar com a regex [desta resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167965/28595) em outra pergunta eu havia feito, mas agora preciso mesclar uma regex pra verificar se o nome do arquivo é todo maiúsculo, negando a regex da resposta linkada, pro caso de ter o trecho citado.

Pra demonstrar o que quero fazer:

```
EDSON ARANTES DO NASCIMENTO.jpg -> passa
EDsON ARANTEs DO NASCIMENTO.jpg -> não passa
EDSON ARANTES DO NASCIMENTO - Cópia.jpg -> não passa
EDSON ARANTES DO NASCIMENTO. - Cópia - Cópia.jpg -> não passa
```

A regex que fiz até agora foi:

```
^([A-Z]{2,}+).*( - C[oó]pia\.[^.]+)$
```

mas isso deixa passar todos os casos acima. Até encontrei esta [outra resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/5524514) mas não sei como aplicar. Como adapto esse código de forma que somente o primeiro exemplo passe?

Comment: Dá uma olhada a esta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42172/129 ou esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143866/129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi essa:

```
^([^a-z]{1,}[A-Z]{2,}+)(?:(?! - C[oó]pia\.[^.]+).)+$
```

Basicamente são dois grupos, onde o primeiro não permite letras minúsculas em qualquer quantidade, e somente maiúsculos a partir de 2 caracteres seguidos(estranhamente só funciona com essa limitação, se remover não funciona corretamente). O segundo grupo nega a regex da [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167965/28595).

A validação pode ser conferida no [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CjRMPK/1).

Answer (score 1):

### Expresão REGEX

```
(([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ])([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]{3,}))|([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ])
```

### Expresão de substituição

```
\U$2\E\L$3\E\L$4\E
```

### Explicação

Vamos dividir a expressão regex em suas partes:

```
1 (
2    ([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ])
3    ([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]{3,})
4 )|
5 ([A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ])
```

1. `[A-Za-zÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]`: conjunto de caracteres expandido para as acentuações usadas em português e algumas letras bônus.
2. O primeiro grupo definido nas linhas `1` a `4` acima captura todas as palavras com 4 ou mais caracteres e divide essas palavras em dois grupos, o `$2` com a primeira letra da palavra (que deve ser maiúscula) e o `$3` com o restante da palavra (que deve ser minuscula).
3. O grupo `$4` definido na linha `5` acima captura todos os caracteres nao capturados anteriormente (que vao pertencer às palavras com 3 ou menos caracteres)
4. A expressão de substituição utiliza os grupos e as condições especiais:

   - `\U\E`: indica que o que estiver entre `\U` e o `\E` deve ser maisculo
   - `\L\E`: indica que o que estiver entre `\L` e o `\E` deve ser minusculo

Comment: Acentos são irrelevantes pro meu problema, pois não usamos para renomear os arquivos, por isso não citei. E essa regex ai está deixando passar todos os exemplos da pergunta que mencionei que não deveriam passar.

Comment: Articuno, me desculpe, mas parece que você alterou totalmente a questão perguntada inicialmente, respondi sua pergunta inicial...

Comment: Sua resposta foi postada após a alteração. Quando a pergunta não tem respostas, alterar completamente é perfeitamente aceitável e permitido. Tanto que já até postei a solução pro novo problema. E o problema inicial eu já havia resolvido de outra forma, então reaproveitei a pergunta.

Comment: Sim eu sei, estava redigindo a resposta e não vi a alteração... só estou justificando o porquê da minha resposta não responder a sua pergunta atual...

Comment: Ah, perdão então, mas como eu já havia resolvido e não tinha respostas, eu resolvi aproveitar a mesma pra outro problema que surgiu. :/