# Abreviar nomes com javascript

Tags: javascript, split

Olá
Eu estou querendo escrever uma função para reduzir nomes passando um limite, por exemplo: limite 10 para o nome: Sara Flávia Cristina para Sara F. C.

Escrevi o código abaixo, mas gostaria de saber se tem uma forma mais simples de fazer isso.

Obrigada.

```
let name = "Sara Flávia Cristina";
let limit = 13;
verifyName(name, limit);

function verifyName(name, limit) {
  let offLimit = isOffLimit(name, limit);

  if(offLimit > 0) {
    let namesList = splitName(name);
    let reducedName = reduceName(namesList, limit, offLimit);
    print(reducedName);
  }
}

function isOffLimit(name, limit) {
  if(name.length >= limit) {
    return limit - name.length;
  } 
}

function splitName(name, limit) {
  return name.split(" ", limit);
}

function reduceName(namesList, limit, offLimit) {
  let name;
  let reduceOfLimit = limit;

  for (var i = 0; i < namesList.length; i++) {   
    name = countName(namesList[i]);
    if(reduceOfLimit != 0) {
      if(name.length + 1 == offLimit) {
        namesList[i].slice(0, offLimit);
        namesList[i] + ".";
        reduceOfLimit = 0;
      }
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}

function countName(name) {
  return name.length;
}

function print(string) {
  console.log(string);
}
´´´
```

Comment: O que significa o "limite 10"? E se esse valor fosse diferente, qual seria a saída, por exemplo para limite 15? E para limite 50? Ou limite 5?

Comment: Também não compreendi bem o limite, é se o nome for maior que o limite aí abrevia os sobrenomes, se for menor ou igual o nome não sofre alteração?

Comment: Se passa o limite faz a abreviação, se não mantem o texto original. @Woss

Comment: E se tiveres "António de Sousa" ou "Maria da Conceição d'Espada" como será a versão abreviada?

Comment: seria Maria C. E. e Antonio S.

Comment: Como você abreviaria "*Pedro de Alcântara Francisco António João Carlos Xavier de Paula Miguel Rafael Joaquim José Gonzaga Pascoal Cipriano Serafim*"?

Comment: @VictorStafusa D. Pedro I sempre quebra qualquer teste... :-)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda de todos, consegui adequar o meu código baseado na ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, deve ser isto.

**Segue o código:**

```
console.log(abridgedControl('Sabrina Boing Moreira', 13)); //Sabrina B. M.

function abridgedControl(fullName, limit) {
    if (fullName.length > limit) {
        return toAbridged(fullName);
    }
    return fullName;
}


function toAbridged(fullName) { 
    const token = '.';
    const separator = ' ';
    const names = removePrepositions(fullName).split(separator);
    const firstName = names[0];
    let surnames = '';
    names
        .filter((name, index) => index)
        .map(name => surnames += `${separator}${name.charAt()}${token}`);
    return `${firstName}${surnames.toUpperCase()}`;
}

function removePrepositions(fullName) {
    return fullName.replace(/\ dos|\ das|\ dos|\ das|\ de|\ d\'/gi, '');
}
```

Tomei liberdade para retirar as preposições mais conhecidas.

Comment: Perfeito, era isso, muito obrigada, vou adequar meu código.

Answer (score 2):

Isto é mais complexo que parece e o JavaScript não é muito bom nisto pois é difícil detectar letras maiúsculas. Letras como `Ì`, `Ó`, `Å` são maiúsculas mas uma regex com `A-Z` não as apanha. Na verdade [a lista de possibilidades é gigante](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm). Dá uma olhada [a esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42172/como-tranformar-em-caixa-alta-a-primeira-letra-de-palavras-dentro-de-uma-string) que tem um problema semelhante.

Tendo dito isto, e considerando apenas algumas letras grandes mais comuns, poderias fazer assim:

```js
const testes = [
  "António de Sousa",
  "Maria da Conceição d 'Espada",
  "Johan Öström",
  "Joana Ìlhavo"
];

function abreviar(str) {
  const [nome, ...sobrenomes] = str.split(' ');

  const abreviaturas = sobrenomes.reduce((arr, str) => {
    const letraGrande = str.match(/[A-ZÖÄÅÀÁÂÃÌÍÒÓÉÊÚ]/);
    if (!letraGrande) return arr;
    return arr.concat(`${letraGrande[0]}.`);
  }, []);

  return [nome, ...abreviaturas].join(' ');
}

testes.forEach((teste, i) => {
  console.log(i, '>', abreviar(teste));
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo exemplo, resolveu o meu problema de forma muito mais simples da linha de pensamento que eu estava seguindo.